# proc/sys/vm/flush_mmap_pages missing in 3.9 kernel, how to get it?

Tags: kernel, mmap

There was an option in redHat 5.2 called `flush_mmap_pages`, I could set this to zero and that would turn of writing dirty pages from a mapped memory file (so I can do it myself when I want to). However it is missing in newer kernels, I am using fedora 17 on Linux 3.9 kernel ATM and it is not there. Is there anyway to apply a kernel patch to get it back, does anybody know the last kernel version to support this kernel parameter?

Answer (score 2):

If it is not present in the new kernels, it means that the maintainers decided for this section of code decided not to provide this facility.  This capability could have been moved or combined with some other capability, but you'll have to research this to find out.

I would approach patching to get some old capability very carefully if it is NOT in the current kernel.  You might well introduce some serious instability.